# How to count the number of ones in a byte without a loop in c?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best algorithm to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Hello,

Is there a more compact way of counting the number of ones in a byte without using a loop? I don't want to do the following if I don't have to. Thanks.

```
char myValue = 0x0F;

int counter = 0;

while (myValue > 0)
{
 if (myValue & 0x01)
 {
  counter ++;
 }

 myValue = myValue >> 1;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer

Comment: Are you asking for a solution in C? C++? objective-c?  These are all very different languages.  The solution is going to be slightly different for each one.

Comment: @wheaties: I'm pretty sure C and C++ don't differ here.

Comment: @vitaut: not a duplicate question, but there's definitely a duplicate answer.

Comment: @Paul Nathan in C++ I'd just put it into a `std::bitset` and then call the `bitset::count` function.  In C, that doesn't exist.

Comment: C, C++, objective-c at this level are approximatively equivalent. Only a few general purpose processor provide bitcount instruction. This instruction has been introduced on x86 when the MMX instruction set has been added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 ((i>>3)&1)+((i>>2)&1)+((i>>1)&1)+(i&1)
```

Or use assembly (SSE/MMX).
http://gurmeet.net/puzzles/fast-bit-counting-routines/

Comment: Your code is a sum of four brackets, each bracket can be either 0 or 1. So the result can be at most four, but there can be 8 ones in a Byte.

Answer (score 0):

This works if you initialize the table correctly.

```
static const unsigned char one_bits_in_byte[] = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, ... };

int counter = one_bits_in_byte[myValue & 0xFF];
```

Of course, you'd write a program with a loop in it to generate the table so that your final program doesn't have a loop in it.  If you are feeling cost conscious, you can encode just the data for 0..15 and process the two halves (nybbles) of the value with shifts.  But with [24 GB](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/01/24-gigabytes-of-memory-ought-to-be-enough-for-anybody.html) of physical memory, this is unlikely to be a major problem.  And you could also simply compute the value on demand with masking operations, etc (like [VGE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548829/vge) suggests, but extended to a whole byte).

Comment: If you're going to be cost-conscious, presumably it won't be about your 2/4GB of physical memory, it will be about your L1 cache. RAM is just L4 cache for the page file anyway ;-)

Comment: @Steve: +1 your "L4" comment made me laugh! :-)